# Validation for AlphaNumeric and Line break

Tags: .net

On a text box I have to allow Alphanumeric characters with a enter key ( line break) so multilne message can be formed. What should be the regular expression to allow these keys ?
Right now I use

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9_ ()'-]+$"
```

which doesn't allow enter key.

Thanks

Comment: I get following error on this expression.  ^[A-Za-z0-9_ ()'-\n]+$ is not a valid regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

@"^[A-Za-z0-9\n\r_ ()'-]+$";   worked for me.